# Access facetSolrSearch/indexing to usergroup in hybris

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I have created a new usergroup and have given permission to read,write,delete Types and attributes. Here I observe I am not able to access Facet Search configuration through backoffice with that user. I dont want to assign 'admingroup' to the user. Is there any type or attribute to which I can assign access to that user such that user can run indexing.

Below is impex I have used to assign role :-

```
$START_USERRIGHTS;;;;;;;;;
Type;UID;MemberOfGroups;Password;Target;read;change;create;remove;change_perm
UserGroup;nextAdmintGroup;;;;;;;;

;;;;Consignment;+;-;-;-;-
;;;;ConsignmentEntry;+;-;-;-;-
;;;;ConsignmentStatus;+;-;-;-;-
;;;;PackagingInfo;+;-;-;-;-


;;;;Principal;+;-;-;-;-
;;;;User;+;+;+;-;-
;;;;Customer;+;+;+;-;-
;;;;CustomerType;+;+;+;-;-
;;;;Employee;+;+;+;-;-
;;;;Customer.customerID;+;-;-;-;-;
;;;;Customer.uid;+;-;-;-;-;
;;;;EmployeeBenefit;+;-;-;-;-

;;;;RewardPoints;+;+;+;-;-
;;;;Cronjob;+;+;+;-
;;;;Job;+;-;-;-
;;;;CartEntry;+;+;+;-
;;;;Cart;+;+;+;-
;;;;Order;+;-;-;-
;;;;Referral;+;+;+;-
;;;;UserBirthday;+;+;+;-
;;;;Customer.managementHold;+;+;+;-
;;;;SavedValues;+;-;-;-
;;;;SavedValueEntry;+;-;-;-
;;;;Customer.defaultPaymentInfo;+;-;-;-


;;;;AbstractOrder;+;-;-;-;-
;;;;AbstractOrderProcessingStep;+;-;-;-;-
;;;;OrderEntry;+;-;-;-;-
;;;;OrderStatus;+;-;-;-;-
;;;;AbstractOrderEntry;+;-;-;-;-
;;;;AbstractOrderEntry.Product;+;-;-;-;-
;;;;OrderModificationRecord;+;-;-;-;-
;;;;OrderEntryModificationRecordEntry;+;-;-;-;-
;;;;OrderCancelRecordEntry;+;-;-;-;-
;;;;OrderEntryCancelRecordEntry;+;-;-;-;-
;;;;OrderHistoryEntry;+;-;-;-;-

;;;;PaymentMode;+;;;
;;;;PaymentInfo;+;-;-;-
;;;;Format;+;;;
;;;;Agreement;+;+;+;+
;;;;Title;+;;;
;;;;Company;+;+;+;+
;;;;UserGroup;+;;;
;;;;Discount;+;;;
;;;;Order;+;-;-;-
;;;;Cart;+;-;-;-

;;;;Address;+;+;+;-;-
;;;;Country;+;+;-;-;-
;;;;Region;+;+;-;-;-
;;;;ZoneDeliveryModeValue;+;+;-;-;-
;;;;DeliveryMode;+;+;-;-;-


# Access Rights for Products & Catalog;;;;;;;;;

;;;;ItemSyncTimestamp;+;;;
;;;;SyncItemJob;+;;;
;;;;Type;+;;;
;;;;Product;+;+;+;-;-;
;;;;Category;+;+;+;-;-;
;;;;variantType;+;+;+;-;-;
;;;;Catalog;+;;;
;;;;CatalogVersion;+;+;+;-;-;
;;;;ClassificationAttributeUnit;+;;;
;;;;Media;+;+;+;-;-;
;;;;MediaContainer;+;+;+;-;-;
;;;;MediaFormat;+;+;+;-;-;
;;;;MediaFolder;+;+;+;-;-;
;;;;Vendor;+;+;+;-;-;
;;;;StockLevel;+;+;+;-;-;
;;;;Tax;+;+;+;-;-;
;;;;TaxRow;+;+;+;+-;-;
;;;;PriceRow;+;+;+;-;-;
;;;;ProductFeature;+;+;+;-;-;
;;;;ProductReference;+;+;+;-;-;
;;;;Warehouse;+;+;+;-;-;
;;;;ProductTaxCode;+;+;+;-;-;
;;;;ProductOrderLimit;+;+;+;-;-;
;;;;PromotionSourceRule;+;+;+;-;-;
;;;;PromotionSourceRuleTemplate;+;+;+;-;;
;;;;PromotionGroup;+;+;+;-;;
;;;;AbstractCoupon;+;+;+;-;;
;;;;CouponRedemption;+;;;;;
;;;;CodeGenerationConfiguration;+;;;;;
;;;;BTGConfig;+;+;+;-;;
;;;;Voucher;+;+;+;-;;
;;;;RuleGroup;+;-;-;-;-;
;;;;RuleStatus;+;-;-;-;-;
;;;;Campaign;+;-;-;-;-;



;;;;AbstractComponentContainer;+;+;+;+;+;
;;;;AbstractComponentContainer.itemtype;+;-;-;-;-;
;;;;AbstractCMSComponent;+;+;+;+;+;
;;;;AbstractCMSComponent.itemtype;;-;-;-;-;
;;;;AbstractCMSAction;+;+;+;+;+;
;;;;AbstractCMSAction.itemtype;;-;-;-;-;
;;;;SimpleCMSAction;+;+;+;+;+;
;;;;PickUpInStoreAction;+;+;+;+;+;
;;;;AddToCartAction;+;+;+;+;+;
;;;;ShareOnSocialNetworkAction;+;+;+;+;+;
;;;;AbstractPage;+;+;+;+;+;
;;;;AbstractPage.itemtype;;-;-;-;-;
;;;;AbstractRestriction;+;+;+;+;+;
;;;;AbstractRestriction.itemtype;;-;-;-;-;
;;;;BaseStore;+;-;-;-;-
;;;;BaseSite;+;-;-;-;-
;;;;CMSItem;+;+;+;+;+;
;;;;CMSItem.itemtype;;-;;;;
;;;;CMSRelation;+;+;+;+;+;
;;;;CMSCatalogRestriction;;;+;+;+;
;;;;CMSCategoryRestriction;;;+;+;+;
;;;;CMSProductRestriction;;;+;+;+;
;;;;CatalogPage;-;-;-;-;-;
;;;;CategoryPage;;;+;+;+;
;;;;ContentCatalog;+;+;+;-;-;
;;;;ContentPage;;;+;+;+;
;;;;ContentSlot;+;+;+;+;+;
;;;;ContentSlotForPage;+;+;+;+;+;
;;;;ContentSlotForTemplate;+;+;+;+;+;
;;;;ContentSlotName;+;+;+;+;+;
;;;;ElementsForContainer;+;+;+;+;+;
;;;;ElementsForSlot;+;+;+;+;+;
;;;;CMSImageComponent;;;+;+;+;
;;;;BannerComponent;;;+;+;+;
;;;;CMSLinkComponent;;;+;+;+;
;;;;Media;+;+;+;+;+;
;;;;CockpitUIScriptConfigMedia;-;-;-;-;-;
;;;;MediaContainer;+;+;+;+;+;
;;;;MediaContext;+;+;+;+;+;
;;;;MediaFormat;+;+;+;+;+;
;;;;MediaFormatMapping;+;+;+;+;+;
;;;;PageRestrictions;+;+;+;+;+;
;;;;PageTemplate;+;+;+;+;+;
;;;;CMSParagraphComponent;;;+;+;+;
;;;;ProductPage;;;+;+;+;
;;;;SimpleCMSComponent;;;+;+;+;
;;;;CatalogsForCMSSite;+;+;+;+;+;
;;;;AvailableSlotsForTemplate;+;+;+;+;+;
;;;;RestrictionsForPages;+;+;+;+;+;
;;;;CatalogsForRestriction;+;+;+;+;+;
;;;;CategoriesForRestriction;+;+;+;+;+;
;;;;ProductsForRestriction;+;+;+;+;+;
;;;;UsersForRestriction;+;+;+;+;+;
;;;;UserGroupsForRestriction;+;+;+;+;+;
;;;;PreviewDataToCatalogVersion;+;+;+;+;+;
;;;;PreviewData;+;+;+;+;+;
;;;;CMSSite;+;+;+;-;-;
;;;;MiniCartComponent;+;+;+;+;+;
;;;;CategoryFeatureComponent;+;+;+;+;+;
;;;;ProductFeatureComponent;+;+;+;+;+;
;;;;ProductVariantSelectorComponent;+;+;+;+;+;
;;;;ProductAddToCartComponent;+;+;+;+;+;
;;;;ProductReferencesComponent;+;+;+;+;+;
;;;;SimpleSuggestionComponent;+;+;+;+;+;
;;;;PurchasedCategorySuggestionComponent;+;+;+;+;+;
;;;;CartSuggestionComponent;+;+;+;+;+;
;;;;SearchBoxComponent;+;+;+;+;+;
;;;;CMSMediaParagraphComponent;+;+;+;+;+;
;;;;CMSUiExperienceRestriction;+;+;+;+;+;
;;;;CMSActionRestriction;+;+;+;+;+;
;;;;AccountNavigationComponent;+;+;+;+;+;
;;;;AccountNavigationCollectionComponent;+;+;+;+;+;
;;;;JspIncludeComponent;+;+;+;+;+;
;;;;AccountBookmarkComponent;+;+;+;+;+;
;;;;Usb2cNavigationBarComponent;+;+;+;+;+;
;;;;CDPPersonalizedContentComponent;+;+;+;+;+; 

$END_USERRIGHTS;;;;;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research I was able to fix this. Added below line in impex code mentioned in question

```
;;;;SolrFacetSearchConfig;+;+;+;-;-;
```